# Need to perform a operation in which there will be multiple users send request whereas each request taking higher time to execute single operation

Tags: c#, .net-core, backend

Here we are using angular 9 as Front end and .net core 3.1 as backend and sql server as db.

Each user will send single request to server but to execute each request server is taking almost 90 minutes for its operations.

Need to find solution for backend to hold all request or to execute some request at a time but it should not overlap the existing running request calculations.

We are thinking to bring Queue in backend already tried parallel foreach but it is messing up some calculations.
Is there any other way you can help me??
Thanks in advance

Comment: `but it should not overlap the existing running request calculations.` - then why are you trying to do it in _parallel_? parallelism is exactly that: calculations _overlapping_.

Comment: It was just try to do parallel for the first time. Now we are moving forward and try to achieve this using Channel https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ and store req in queue. Actually we were looking for solution which help us to execute multiple request at a time but it will increase load on server bcz operations are to heavy

Answer (score 0):

Sounds for me you have an asynchronous operation. So there are multiple solutions from my point of view I will describe two simple once which  you easily can extend.

First you have to seperate the trigger of your „job“ and query the state.

With your less given informations about the whole system I assume you have running an api on a server. So you could use the files system to persist the running jobs and query them vie seperate request. So one request scheduled the „job“ and the other returns the information of the state.

Of there is no file system you also can use a database for this or just store it in memory ( be aware of undesired restarts of the programme drop your infos).

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your quick reply. Now we are using Channels https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ will store requests in queue and pop it once one request is completed its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this functionality using Hangfire: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/